# QueryMethodParameterConversionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to access JPA Data with REST using spring-boot-starter-data-rest. 
I want to use a different method than the CrudRepository has. But the framework responds with the following exception:

```
exception is org.springframework.data.repository.support.QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert Brazil into hello.Country!] with root cause
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param hello.Country]
```

**Endpoint**

http://localhost:8080/rest/cities/search/findByCountry?name=Brazil

**CityRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "cities", path = "cities")
public interface  CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

    List<City> findByCountry(@Param("name") Country country);

}
```

**City.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "City")
public class City implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonInclude(value=Include.ALWAYS)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @Embedded
    private Country country;

    protected City() {}

    public City(long id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = nome;
    }    

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
```

**Country.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="country")
    private Set<City> cities;        

    protected Country() {}

    public Country(long id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = nome;
    }
```

When I call http://localhost:8080/rest/cities/ , I get the list of cities normally. I setted the configureRepositoryRestConfiguration to config.setBasePath("/rest");

Comment: What aboutn the call `...findByCountry?name={name:"Brazil"}`? Looks like it expects json value

Comment: Country isn't a String, and I don't see a converter set up. Research those. You could also start here: this question has a decent example of a simple converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628063/no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-java-lang-string-to-type-org

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.String != hello.Country
```

In accordance with the documentation, we need to:

1. [Use ResponseBody with consumes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes)
2. Or create object from `String` like in [REST hello world example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to resolve this issue, using a nativeQuery:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM City c JOIN Country co 
ON c.country_id = co.id WHERE co.name 
LIKE (CONCAT_WS('%',:name, '%'))", nativeQuery = true) 
List<City> country(@Param("name") String name);
```