# How to use custom Spring Converter to convert XML config values?

Tags: java, xml, spring, type-conversion

I want to use the Spring `ConversionService` with custom `Converter` implementations to convert values from Spring XML config.

I configure a bean through xml config like this:

```
<bean name="A1" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg name="time" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

The associated class:

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(Duration time) {
        System.out.println("TIME: " + time);
    }
}
```

The converter that should perform the conversion is:

```
public class StringToDurationInSecondsConverter implements Converter<String, Duration> {
    @Override
    public Duration convert(String source) {
        int seconds = Integer.valueOf(source);
        return Duration.ofSeconds(seconds);
    }
}
```

The config looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService(
            Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters,
            ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory) {
        factory.setConverters(converters);
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean() {
        return new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToDurationInSecondsConverter stringToDurationInSecondsConverter() {
        return new StringToDurationInSecondsConverter();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The converters are injected as expected into `conversionService` method, so that the `conversionService` should be properly initialized. But the conversion of the parameter `time` in the xml config could not be performed. The error message is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'A1' defined in resource loaded through SAX InputSource: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.Duration]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

If I set a breakpoint into my `convert` method it is never reached. So it looks like the converter is never called.

Even If I inject the `ConversionService` directly to the (modified) `MyClass` and call the `convert` method within the constructor ...

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String time, ConversionService conversionService) {
        final Duration duration = conversionService.convert(time, Duration.class);
        System.out.println(duration);
    }
}
```

... I get the exception:

> ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.Duration]

The core of the application is configured with Springs Java config, but there is some more "volatile" config that is read from a file by another bean (what works apart from the conversion).

Is it possible to use Spring's ConversionService with custom `Converter`s to convert values in a Spring xml config? How?

Comment: it seems to be failing to create the bean instance of `A1`. what is the code for class `MyClass` and what is the type of `time` in that class. from the error stack it looks like `time` is of type `java.time.Duration` to which you are trying to assign 10 as string literal while bean creation.

Comment: The type of `time` is `java.time.Duration`. And I'm indeed passing the String `"10"` to this constructor, but it should be converted to `Duration` in between. I've added my example class to the question.

Comment: I don't think that the way you are trying to use converterService is in correct context. The converterServices are for you to use in your code NOT in a way so spring automatically convert the argument types when instantiating a bean. Take a look at official documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

Comment: But even If I inject the converter directly, no appropriate converter is found.

Comment: how are you registering your custom converter class `StringToDurationInSecondsConverter`?

Comment: I register it with `@Bean` annotated factory method in my Spring Java config as you can see in the 4th code block above.

Comment: i don't think adding the converter to spring context is enough. You need to register it to the converterService refer to accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628063/no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-java-lang-string-to-type-org and official doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had read the section of the reference, but it seemed to me that using `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` would be enough as the first example suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364012/why-is-spring-conversionservice-null/46364314#comment79692260_46364012) of [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) (on another question) I came to the following solution:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    final ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet(); // necessary
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Converting attribute values from XML works fine now.