# Use ConversionServiceFactoryBean or GenericConversionService to register custom converters?

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a `ConversionService` with custom converters.

Inspired by another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273443/how-to-configure-spring-conversionservice-with-java-config) I've tried to create a `ConversionService` by creating a `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` and setting the converters on it:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService(
        Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters,
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory) {
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean() {
    return new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
}
```

The [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config) suggests more or less the same in XML:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="example.MyCustomConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But configuring a `ConversionService` did not work in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361184/how-to-use-custom-spring-converter-to-convert-xml-config-values). Did not work means following error was thrown when i tried to use this autowired `conversionService` in my class;

```
ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.Duration]
```

I had to use a `GenericConversionService` and add my converters to it:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    final GenericConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
    converters.forEach(conversionService::addConverter);
    return conversionService;
}
```

Now it works, but I want to understand why it doesn't work with `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

Why doesn't it work with `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` and Java config? Why does it work with `GenericConversionService`?

Comment: It's still unclear to me what _did not work_ means. Please extract the relevant parts of that link into your question here. Present a [mcve] that demonstrates whichever failure you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to register the converter in your `conversionService` method after the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` bean has been initialised
i.e. `afterPropertiesSet` has already been called while constructing the factory bean. If you want to use the first method in your question the converter needs to be registered before afterPropertiesSet method gets called. so I would change your `conversionService` and `conversionServiceFactoryBean` methods as follows;

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService(ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory) {
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    return factory;
}
```

However separating these two methods serves no purpose as the instance of `conversionService` would have already been registered in spring context. So better to just merge those two methods as following;

**Note the method name is changed from `conversionServiceFactoryBean` to `conversionService`.** Without the name change Spring will throw an exception failing to convert the data as intended.

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    return factory;
}
```

The spring xml example you quoted above can be converted to java config as above in the single method.

Comment: In your first proposed solution, the `ConversionService` `@Bean` method is useless. The `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` `@Bean` will already implicitly place a `ConversionService` bean in the context. Spring calls `FactoryBean#getObject` itself on factory beans.

Comment: And fixing that makes your second solution look unnecessary since Spring does all the work for us anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for comments. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The solution can be simplified by calling `afterPropertiesSet` explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364314/238134